# Can I create Route::filter with another filter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and I want to use a filter which in turns checks with another filter. Following is a piece of code.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
    // write code here
    }
});

Route::filter('logged_in_as_user',array('before'=>'auth', function()
{
    // check if user is a normal user
}));

Route::filter('logged_in_as_admin', array('before'=>'auth', function()
{
    // check if user is a admin user
}));

Route::get('user/dashboard',array('before'=>'logged_in_as_user', function() {
   //make view
}));

Route::get('user/dashboard',array('before'=>'logged_in_as_admin', function() {
   //make view
    }));

Route::post('/login', function()
{
    Auth::attempt( array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')) );
    if(Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('user/dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('flash_error', 'User Name or password not match');
    }
});
```

Its more like I wan to have Role Based Authentication.

I get an error as

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   second array member is not a valid method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, because filter() just accepts a closure in that second parameter:

```
public function filter($name, $callback)
{
    $this->events->listen('router.filter: '.$name, $this->parseFilter($callback));
}
```

But you can use route group:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function()
{

    Route::group(['before' => 'logged_in_as_user'], function()
    {
        Route::get('user/dashboard', function() {
            //make view
        });
    }

    Route::group(['before' => 'logged_in_as_admin'], function()
    {
        Route::get('user/dashboard', function() {
            //make view
        });
    }

});
```

And, of course, create your filters normally:

```
Route::filter('logged_in_as_user', function()
{
    // check if user is a normal user
});
```